# PhantomJS: call a user defined/custom function within phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, referenceerror

i'm getting a ReferenceError when i call a function i defined myself inside the page.evaluate() of Phantom; what is the proper way to do that ?

for example:

```
function mySweetFunction(item) {
    // process item....

}

page.evaluate(function(){

    var item= document.getElementsById('item');

    mySweetFunction(item);

});
```

then i'll get the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: mySweetFunction

What is the proper way to do this ?

mySweetFunction is quite big, and i would prefer to keep it out of page.evaluate(...) if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a function inside page.evaluate() you have to put it there first:

```
page.evaluate(function(){

    function mySweetFunction(item) {
        // process item....
    }

    var item = document.getElementsById('item');

    mySweetFunction(item);

});
```

Comment: yea, but the function is really big, so i wanted keep it out for clarity....

Comment: @Xsmael: Unfortunately this is basically the only way to do it. The `page.evaluate` function extracts the function passed to it as a string which is then injected into the javascript interpreter of the page in phantom.js (which is not the interpreter running your code) to be eval'd

Comment: @slebetman thanks for these details, improved my understanding.